# Cannot pass pod spec lint validation on some localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, cocoapods

I have a big project using localization. As for now, I'm using library:

> **'Localize-Swift', '2.0.0'**

to make localization easier.

But since I **upgraded** my xcode to the **latest version 10.0** from **version 9.4.1** some of the localization strings are having a problem such as this :

> xcodebuild:  error: unexpected duplicate task: CopyStringsFile /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cxnnzigdonvocggyjllrudhwfpwq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/myProject/myProject.framework/jp.lproj/Localizable_Chat.strings myProject/myProject/Core/Resources/jp.lproj/Localizable_Chat.strings (in target 'myProject')

I figured there seems to be nothing wrong with the localization library since apparently there are **4 strings to validate** on pod spec lint, **but 1 string DID passed.**

**Difference between those strings :**

> 1. String **passed pod spec lint validation** comes from the **storyboard**.
> 2. Strings with **above error** comes from **Xibs**.

Edited :

> I already **tried** both cocoapods 1.5.3 and 1.6.0 and it's still not
>   working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Update : This was fixed with the new Xcode 10.1 Beta 3**